# How can I rename sub-directories -- normal way doesn't seem to work

Tags: python, rename

So I *thought* I understood well how to do this but it isn't working and I'm hoping some here will have an idea on where I might be going wrong.

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(maindir):
    path = root.split(os.sep)
        if os.path.basename(root).find(".") > -1: #we find dot numbers
            print (root)
            holdlen = root.find(".")
            holdp = root[:holdlen] + "__material"
            print (holdp)
            os.rename(root,holdp)
```

I'm looking to rename folders that have this sort of spec:

V:\myfolder\mymaterial.003__material

to:

V:\myfolder\mymaterial__material

I can do this manually (so it's not a case of, say, the folder already existing or some other element being wrong) and the printout says it's correct (which is to say it shows the name previous and then the correct name to rename) but while it doesn't throw any errors it also doesn't rename the folder.

I'm stumped -- don't even know what to try now.  Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

I found the fix.

I've renamed files in this manner before but, of course, these are folders and need the backslash to delimit them.  The code above works if you append backslash to the end of both the folder name as well as the name you are renaming it to.

Interestingly, it did not throw any errors for this problem.